# Android-Java RSA decrypt

Tags: java, android, rsa, public-key

i need to create a public key for RSA algorithm from a binary string.

My code is:

```
String pubKey = "tihq/Gk3OUs5NzP+XTRKXBwSxHtB0TWn0RREcpXEtp316tyD9DzKaIbdKexb/mRr";

byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(pubKey,Base64.DEFAULT);
//test if is correct: ok
Log.d("response keyBytes",new String(Base64.encode(keyBytes,Base64.DEFAULT)));

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");      
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);

RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
//PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
```

But i have this error:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED.
The problem is that i have modulus and exponent and so i must to do this:

```
String pubKey = "tihq/Gk3OUs5NzP+XTRKXBwSxHtB0TWn0RREcpXEtp316tyD9DzKaIbdKexb/mRr"; //64 caratteri
String exponent = "AQAB";

byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(pubKey,Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] exponentByte = Base64.decode(exponent,Base64.DEFAULT);

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

RSAPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(keyBytes), new BigInteger(exponentByte));
RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
```